# Random number generator in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, dom, random

How can add the following JavaScript code (a random number generator)?

```
function randomNumber(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max + 1);
}

const list = []
while(list.length < 25) {
    let nbr = randomNumber(25)
    if(!list.find(el => el === nbr)) 
        list.push(nbr)
}

console.log("list",list)
```

into this textarea and displaying them with DOM?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('textarea').textContent = list.join(', ');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Using an id to get the element
const textarea = document.getElementById('area');

function randomNumber(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max + 1);
}

const list = []
while(list.length < 25 ){
    let nbr = randomNumber(25)
    if(!list.find(el => el === nbr)) 
        list.push(nbr)
}

// Set the value to the list
textarea.value = list;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea name="" id="area" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```